# PHP: ¿Cómo ejecutar en segundo plano? (en Windows)

Tags: php, procesos-en-segundo-plano

Justamente eso, deseo ejecutar un fichero en segundo plano, he encontrado el siguiente código pero no se como aplicarlo:

```
exec(sprintf("%s > %s 2>&1 & echo $! >> %s", $cmd, $outputfile, $pidfile));
```

Pasa que no comprendo que debe ir dentro de $cmd, y $pidfile. Asumo que $outputfile es el nombre del fichero que quiero que me devuelva, no? Espero sus comentarios.

Answer (score 1):

Bueno encontré la forma:

```
exec("C:/ruta/a/tu/php/php.exe C:/ruta/a/tu/archivo/archivo.php");
```

Comment: Al final, era problema de rutas ?

Comment: Si brother, era problemas de rutas, porque las variables de sistemas la tenía bien puestas.

Comment: Mas bien que pena que borraste tu posteo pudiste haberlo editado para el caso de Linux, estuvo muy bueno.

Comment: Creo que fué `Al Capone` el que dijo `Sin testigos` ;-) Siempre puedo volver a hacerlo, si es necesario. Es que no venia a cuento de tu problema, una vez que me quedó claro el tema. Que quieres, asustar a posibles nuevos usuarios de Linux o de PHP ?? xD